# Ask about Past simple and past continuous tense

Tags: simple-past

Which one I should choose for this sentence: As soon as we walked into the room, we (were hearing/heard)_____ a noise. Someone (used/was using)______ my computer.

I think I will choose "heard" & "was using" because the act of hearing happened in the middle of the act of using computer.

Please help, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you are a beginner in English, you might be better using the English Language Learners' forum https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for your support,